# Posting a Firebase Storage Download URL to an External API

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, shopify-app

**Background**

I'd like to use the download url generated by Firebase storage objects to upload an image to the Shopify API. I'm currently using the Firebase ['put' method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) to add an image file blob direct to Firebase storage. My storage rules allow public read and user authorized write.

```
const storageRef = storage.ref(storage-path);
storageRef.put(image-file-blob).then(snapshot => {
   snapshot.downloadURL;
});
```

I'm then passing that url from firebase to cloud functions to process the API upload to Shopify. Shopify's API requires an access token so the image has to be uploaded from a secure environment. Shopify has a [put method](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/asset#update) for adding images through base64 or image src.

```
const imageData = {
   "asset": {
     "key": `assets/image.jpg`,
     "src": firebaseDownloadURL
   }
}

Shopify.put(`/admin/themes/theme-id/assets.json`, imageData, function (err,data, headers) {

});
```

**The Issue**

When I use the above method, the Shopify API returns data from the uploaded image (no error) but the image file size is always 0. The image is also not in the Shopify dashboard when I navigate to its file. I assume this is because the image did not properly process.

I have tried to upload a variety of different file types and ssl/non ssl based files to Shopify's API. All worked except for the firebase download url.

**What I Think Is Happening**

The firebase download url is only visible and can only be processed by browsers. If a 3rd party api tries to process the image then they hit restrictions because the url is really a 'get' request to Firebase.

**What I Have Tried**

Rather than using the download url, I'm now using the image path in storage to get a signed url within my cloud functions code. Using the [getSignedUrl method](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.8.0/storage/file?method=getSignedUrl). This does work but requires some additional code server side in my functions. I'd love to just pass the firebase download url to Shopify.

**Questions**

- Is it common that the download url isn't able to be processed by 3rd
  party libraries directly?
- Does anyone have a process they've used to
  do something similar with another API (can be Shopify or any api that
  takes an image src as a parameter to upload it to their service.)?

Comment: Have you tried making the images publicly accessible in the Firebase Storage security rules and construct your own url instead?so the url would look something like this: http://storage.googleapis.com/[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME]... the images would have to be publicly accessible though

Comment: Download URLs from the Firbebase SDK should be publicly viewable.  Anyone with the URL can download the content.  If you're seeing different results, please contact support.  Please be absolutely certain you're passing the correct download URL to shopify.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @EmileEsterhuizen that did work. But along with setting the Firebase Storage security rules I had to change some settings in the google cloud console https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've tried going to the firebase console, finding the image in storage and clicking the download url which automatically copies to my clipboard. I assume that is the correct url. I then attempt to do a put request to Shopify using that url and still receive size=0. By using the url from Emiles method postman successfully posts the image to Shopify.

Comment: The download url that automatically comes from firebase storage is supposed to be an unguessable, always public url, and is unaffected by Firebase Storage permissions (I just got confirmation of this from Firebase staff), so technically it should work. It must be something happening on the Shopify side. Also wrt the alternative way of generating the urls, you should be able to set the bucket permissions from the Cloud Console and save yourself some API calls.

Comment: Another thing that may be worth looking into is CORS, although I guess this is mostly a problem when it comes to uploads... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: Thanks for getting that confirmation. Yea it may be an issue on the Shopify side.